# Generate a RollUp sql query

Tags: mysql

I have a problem. Is my SQL query right?

Note: Yes, I know the Join isn't "the best" (my teacher said we should use this and nothing else), but it should be with this join so in the case e.g. `g.geoID = s.geoID` is right.

[image]

The following output is generated by a single SQL statement:

[image]

These values hold for the productGroup "camcorder" in cities in Germany.

```
SELECT Geograhpie.Cities, Time.Years, AVG(Sales.Turnover) as AverageTurnover
FROM Gerographie as g, Sales as s, Time as t, Products as p
WHERE g.geoID = s.geoID
AND s.timeID = t.timeID
AND s.ProductID=p.ProductID
And Product.Productyfamily = "camcorder"
AND g.country = "Germany"
GROUP BY cities, years WITH ROLLUP;
ORDER BY citiesIS NULL, years IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is almost good, for some reason you are putting a part that is just not right, and even if it was inside will make the rollup fail.

```
SELECT   geograhpie.cities,
         time.years,
         Avg(sales.turnover) AS AverageTurnover
FROM     gerographie         AS g,
         sales               AS s,
         time                AS t,
         products            AS p
WHERE    g.geoid = s.geoid
AND      s.timeid = t.timeid
AND      s.productid=p.productid
AND      product.productyfamily = "camcorder"
AND      g.country = "germany"
GROUP BY cities, years WITH rollup;
```

WITH ROLLUP cannot be used with ORDER BY. Some sorting is still possible by using ASC or DESC clauses with the GROUP BY column, although the super-aggregate rows will always be added last.